# Sharing Mac files with windows 10

Tags: windows, macos, file-sharing

I have followed instructions found [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25348?locale=en_US) but I am unable to see the Mac book as a computer in windows 10 network places. Nor can I map it.

Below is what the Mac screen looks like. Even the IP address is not the regular format (numbers). I'm not sure what needs to be done to make this work.

All help is appreciated.

[image]

**Update**
The computer name/workgroup in MAC and PC are the same

[image]

Windows PC name

[image]

Now, you might see a difference between the computer name in the above. I tried both. Naming the computer in MAC under NETBIOS the same as that in Windows and naming it differently (as shown in the pictures). None worked

The IP address in MAC was the same as that when I logged into the windows. Both the windows and MAC OS are on the same PC so not sure if that makes any difference. Started with a  192.

[image]

In windows, when I ping the IP address is worked fine, but probably because the IP address in both MAC and PC are obviously the same. When I tried pinging the computer name (when different in MAC from Windows) it didn't work. I got the following error

[image]

Not sure what more I need to do. Elsewhere, I was told that with the latest version of Windows 10, file sharing isn't possible.

Comment: Any more suggestions anyone ?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

On the Mac, go to  System Preferences > Network.  Then on the active network (WLAN or Ethernet, whatever you use) click Advanced > WINS.

Give the computer a name and the same Workgroup as the Windows computer:
To find the Workgroup on Windows, start Explorer, right-Click "My Computer", "Properties".  This will show the workgroup the Windows-PC is on.  Use the same workgroup on the Mac.

Also make sure that IP-V4 and IP-V6 is enabled on Mac OS (also System Preferences > Network).

You can now try to shortcut to Step 6 and see if it works.  If not, proceed with Step 2.

---

**Step 2:**
On Mac OS open a Terminal and type *ifconfig*.  You should get an output like this.  Find the ip-address (something different than 127.0.0.1):

[image: sample ifconfig]

---

**Step 3:**
On the Windows computer, open a command prompt.  Type *ipconfig* ... this should give you output with an IPv4-Address that starts with the same numbers as the one from the Mac (e.g. also 192.168.1.xxx).

Type *ping 192.168.1.149* (but with your Mac's IP address from step 2).   If that works, type *ping computername* (but with the name you gave your Mac from step1).  Both should result in the same output, like this:

[image: ping output Windows]

---

**Step 4:**

In windows explorer, in the address bar, type \\192.168.1.149  (but again with your IP address).  You should now see your shared folders (thse from your own screenshot).

---

**Step 5:**

\\computername  (but with the name from the mac network config).

This should also show your data folders.

---

**Step 6:**

If all that works, you should also see the Mac in Windows > Explorer > Network (on the left bar in Explorer).

Comment: Ok, I've followed your suggested steps, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've updated the original post with screenshots